Problem with Redirect after Account Deletion in Keycloak
Description
I am trying to implement account deletion functionality in my Flutter application using Keycloak for authentication. The account deletion process is initiated using the parameter kc_action=delete_account. However, after the account is successfully deleted, the redirect back to my application does not occur.
Steps to Reproduce

The user initiates account deletion through a URL with the parameter kc_action=delete_account:

https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=com.my.app://login-callbac&kc_action=delete_account


Keycloak displays the account deletion confirmation form.

The user confirms the account deletion, leading to a POST request:


POST /auth/realms/my-realm/login-actions/required-action?session_code=SESSION_CODE&execution=delete_account&client_id=CLIENT_ID&tab_id=TAB_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: keycloak-server
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


The account is successfully deleted, but no redirect back to my application occurs.

Expected Behavior
After the account is successfully deleted, Keycloak should redirect the user back to the specified URL in the redirect_uri parameter.
Actual Behavior
The account is deleted, but the redirect does not occur. The user remains on the Keycloak page.
Keycloak Configuration

The redirect_uri is specified in the client settings.
The client has permission to perform delete_account.

Logs and Requests
client
I use flutter_appauth:
final authorizationTokenRequest = AuthorizationTokenRequest(
          authClientId, authRedirectUri,
          issuer: authIssuer,
          preferEphemeralSession: true,
          scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
          additionalParameters: {'kc_action': 'delete_account'});


final result = await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(authorizationTokenRequest);

ReAuth Request
GET /auth/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?nonce=NONCE&kc_action=delete_account&response_type=code&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access&code_challenge=CODE_CHALLENGE&redirect_uri=com.my.app://login-callback&client_id=CLIENT_ID&state=STATE HTTP/1.1


ReAuth Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=SESSION_ID;Version=1;Path=/auth/realms/my_realm/;Secure;HttpOnly;SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=SESSION_ID;Version=1;Path=/auth/realms/my_realm/;Secure;HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Set-Cookie: KC_RESTART=RESTART_TOKEN;Version=1;Path=/auth/realms/my_realm/;Secure;HttpOnly

HTML

Send ReAuth Request with data
POST /auth/realms/my_realm/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=SESSION_CODE&execution=EXECUTION_ID&client_id=CLIENT_ID&tab_id=TAB_ID HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=SESSION_ID; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=SESSION_ID; KC_RESTART=RESTART_TOKEN

username=tester&password=tester&credentialId=

Receive ReAuth Response
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=en;Version=1;Path=/auth/realms/my_realm/;Secure;HttpOnly
Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
Location: https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/my_realm/login-actions/required-action?execution=delete_account&client_id=CLIENT_ID&tab_id=TAB_ID

Redirection Request
GET /auth/realms/my_realm/login-actions/required-action?execution=delete_account&client_id=CLIENT_ID&tab_id=TAB_ID HTTP/1.1
Cookie: KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=en; AUTH_SESSION_ID=SESSION_ID; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=SESSION_ID; KC_RESTART=RESTART_TOKEN


Redirection Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
HTML form

Confirm Deletion Request
POST /auth/realms/my_realm/login-actions/required-action?session_code=SESSION_CODE&execution=delete_account&client_id=CLIENT_ID&tab_id=TAB_ID HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=en; AUTH_SESSION_ID=SESSION_ID; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=SESSION_ID; KC_RESTART=RESTART_TOKEN

Confirm Deletion Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

<html>
  <!-- HTML content indicating the account was deleted -->
  User deleted successfully
</html>

Relevant Links

Redirect URL (to app) - after the action is done successfully
How to enable users to delete their own Keycloak account using API?
Keycloak Community: Application Initiated Actions

Question
How can I configure Keycloak to correctly handle the redirect back to my application after account deletion? Is it possible to achieve this with the redirect_uri parameter, or is there another way to handle this?

I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?
